In Android, lay out two buttons to re-flow from in-line to stacked depending on size
The problem is as follows:

I have two buttons
When the content of the two buttons is sufficiently small, I would like them to be in-line, aligned to the left and right of the parent layout, wrapping their content, like so:
When the content of the buttons becomes so long that they can't fit in an in-line arrangement, I would like them to "re-flow" into a vertically stacked and horizontally centered arrangement, wrapping their content, like so:

Question is: Is this something that can be achieved purely with XML?
This really seemed like a perfect place to apply FlexBoxLayout. The problem is that I am failing to find a way to achieve horizontal centering in the stacked arrangement. That's because the in-line arrangement seems to require app:justifyContent="space_between", which then prevents horizontal centering.
Is there something I am missing with FlexBoxLayout? Or perhaps there is another Layout that would allow me to achieve this kind of behavior?
